# How to install RNNoise from this GitHub repo?

Tags: python, github, jupyter-notebook

I am a beginner and I am trying this out on Jupyter Notebook: https://github.com/xiph/rnnoise/issues/69.

I faced a problem with the "Library Installation" part (to download RNNoise from GitHub).

I managed to download the repo, but I was unable to run the code from "./autogen.sh" onwards. I ran the code on Anaconda Prompt. When I tried to run "./autogen.sh", it showed *"'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."*. Then I tried to run "autogen.sh", but I only managed to open a window which has nothing and closed immediately.

I would really appreciate it if someone can guide me on how to install this library.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is that you are not using a similar system as Linux, you can try it on your VMwareWorkstation or Linux Bash shell or MSYS2, or you can intall sh command into your Windows environment. Come on,it`s a simple Question!Use your browser to get some information!